# Springboot 3.0 Jakarta field validations

Tags: spring-boot, bean-validation, jakarta-migration

As javax validations not supported in springboot 3.0. How to do field validations using Jakarta.
imports

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.NotNull;
import jakarta.persistence.Pattern;
```

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Users{

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
Private String username;
@Pattern
Private String username;
@NotNull
Private String username;
}
```

Controller

```
public class UsersController{
   public void saveUser(@Valid @RequestBody Users user){
    repo.save();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to have `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```